# Rundeck - Where do I update rundeck auth token after generating new token?

Tags: rundeck

I am using rundeck rd cli to invoke other jobs from one job. The token was expired but even after updating the user tokens (with no expiration), I can see the same error.

Is there any config file i need to update the token in?

[auth-image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oj57c.png)

Answer (score 0):

you said the property for no expiration tokens is already set, right?
Did you configure it like [this](https://groups.google.com/g/rundeck-discuss/c/P5ux_DIuVQY/m/S4AUI2OqBwAJ)?

```
rundeck.api.tokens.duration.max=0
```

You can restart Rundeck and try again.

Comment: Yes added this to rundeck conf file and restarted and created a new token on the UI. No success.

Answer (score 0):

I had exported the `RD_TOKEN`. Replaced it with a new token and it worked.